# How to validate more than one piece of form data in a dialog box using the library below?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I have a button when clicked a dialog pops up asking user for signup information. I want to validate the information, if the email is an email, if password matches confirmation password etc. I want to use the library provided below. If there is a better library or method can you please provide that method or a link to something that well help me. Trying to create a user signup page in kotlin

So i've tried following some of the documentation to add validation, but if there is more than one EditText box the app just crashes after pressing the signup button in the app. The documentation mentioned something about a recycler view. But not sure how to implement it for this.

```
 implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:input:3.0.0-beta2'
 implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.0.0-beta2'
```

register_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

 <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r_email"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r_city"
            android:hint="City"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r_password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r_confirmPassword"
            android:hint="Confirm password"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



 </LinearLayout>




 </FrameLayout>
```

SigninActivity.kt

```
 link_signup.setOnClickListener {
        register()
    }

    link_forgot.setOnClickListener {
        forgot()

    }

 }

 private fun forgot() {
    val forgot_layout = LayoutInflater.from(this@SignInActivity)
        .inflate(R.layout.forgot_layout, null)

    MaterialDialog(this).show {
        title(text = "Recovery")
        message(text = "Forgot your passsword?")
        icon(R.drawable.ic_reset)
        cancelable(true)  // calls setCancelable on the underlying 
  dialog
        cornerRadius(10f)
        cornerRadius(res = R.dimen.my_corner_radius)
        input(waitForPositiveButton = false, hint = "Email") { 
      dialog, text ->
            val inputField = dialog.getInputField()
            val isValid = text.startsWith("a", true)

            inputField?.error = if (isValid) null else "Must be a 
    valid email!"
            dialog.setActionButtonEnabled(WhichButton.POSITIVE, 
    isValid)
        }
        positiveButton(text = "Submit")
    }


}

private fun register() {

    MaterialDialog(this).show {
        title(text = "Create an account")
        message(text = "Please fill out the information below?")
        customView(R.layout.register_layout, scrollable = true)
        icon(R.drawable.ic_user)
        cancelable(true)  // calls setCancelable on the underlying 
     dialog
        cornerRadius(10f)
        cornerRadius(res = R.dimen.my_corner_radius)
        positiveButton(text = "submit")

    }
```

As mentioned above I would like to be able to check multiple checks for multiple EditText boxes.

Comment: For UI, I think you can do it without a library, and about form validation, you can do that with regex

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Nj6qCtaUqw) I might just use this